# Objective C custom initializer not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to subclass NSDate to add it milliseconds functionality and it looks like this:

Header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DTDate : NSDate

- (id)initWithJavaMillis:(NSInteger)val;
- (NSInteger)getJavaMillis;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "DTDate.h"

@implementation DTDate
{
    NSInteger milliseconds;
}

- (id)initWithJavaMillis:(NSInteger)val
{
    // Main time initialized with whole seconds
    self = [super initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)(val / 1000)];

    // Also hold on to millis part
    if (self)
    {
        milliseconds = val % 1000;
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)getJavaMillis
{
    return [super timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000 + milliseconds;
}

@end
```

Now I'm trying to use it like so:

```
return [DTDate initWithJavaMillis:retVal];
```

`No known class method for selector 'initWithJavaMillis:'`

But it doesn't work. I never used custom initializers before, so it should be something simple. Any pointers?

Comment: Your `getJavaMillis` should not be calling `super`. It should be calling `self`.

Comment: As an aside, your integer is going to overflow. Use a type that can fit the data.

Comment: Good point. Thanks! I was looking at 64bit max and it looks ok, but on 32 bit it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send your `init` message to an *instance*, not to the class:

```
[[DTDate alloc] initWithJavaMillis:retVal];
```

I'd recommend a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) rather than subclassing for your case, though.

Comment: But in SDK they have shorthands so I don't have to "alloc". Can I do it myself?

Comment: Sure; then you need to write a class method to wrap your initializer that does the allocation for you.